# Closing idle connections with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a server application that does not remove idle connections (resulting from for example client or communication failures). Is it possible to configure iptables to monitor activity on sockets and close connections haven't had any activity for a specified amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is anything iptables can do about this.  Iptables generally just operates on packets being pass through the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `tcpkill` to kill connections. On debian you can find it on the `dsniff` package.